# JOIN TWO TABLES WITH KEY VALUES IN TABLE 1 WITH ALL KEY VALUES IN TABLE 2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables

**Table 1:**  With Column Name `Key`
Values:

```
C1
C2
C3
C4
```

**Table 2:** with three columns `Product`, `Category`, `count`

```
P1-C1-2  
P1-C3-4  
P2-C1-3  
P2-C2-4,  
P2-C3-8,   
P3-C3-10,  
P3-C4-2,
```

**Output required:**

```
P1-C1-2  
P1-C2-0  
P1-C3-0  
P1-C4-0  
P2-C1-3  
P2-C2-4,  
P2-C3-8,  
P2-C4-0,  
P3-C1-0,  
P3-C2-0,  
P3-C3-10,  
P3-C4-2
```

Is there any way to do it?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `cross join`

```
select distinct t2.Product, t1.Key, coalesce(t3.count, 0) as count 
from table2 t2 cross join (select [Key] from table1) t1
left join table2 t3 
          on t3.Product = t2.Product and t1.[key] = t3.Category
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to use the cross-join:

```
SELECT [* | column_list]
FROM table1
CROSS JOIN table2;
```

[More on the subject](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t2.Product,t2.Category, case when t2.Category=t1.Category then t2.count ELSE 0 END AS count
FROM table1 t1,table2 t2;
```